# Lightning Experience: External Sharing/Forward This Case

Tags: lightning, salesforce-to-salesforce

I have run into a brick wall trying to figure out how to extend or duplicate the External Sharing functionality in Salesforce Classic to Lightning Experience.

Since the Classic Console is being retired, we have had to quickly migrate users to our newly configured Lightning Service Console for those who need this type of UI. However, the External Sharing related list and functionality is missing and upon some research (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=business_network_intro.htm&type=5) it appears that this is ONLY available in Classic.

Does anyone know if this has been changed to a new name with the Lightning update? We need this in our Org as we have two companies that share/forward cases with eachother.

If this hasn't been replaced in Lightning, then how might I duplicate this functionality in Lightning? I'm not a developer by any means, but if there's a way to create a Visualforce page or a Lightning Component that mimics this functionality I would love to be pointed in the right direction.

I can't imagine this issue hasn't come up before but I've spent hours researching this with no luck. I'm hoping that someone else here has some kind of solution!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at building a flow that creates a share entry to the desired connection. The underlying objects are there, you just need a button to create the entry which you might be able to do with flow.